# Asynchronous HTTP(S) request in existing loop

Tags: http, https, rust

I want to send a HTTPS request to a server but have a problem figuring out how. The best way for me to do it would be to initiate the request and regularly check back whether it has finished. How can I do this? It is even possible? What are the alternatives?

Comment: What code have you tried? Are you using any specific library (like tokio or hyper)?

Comment: I already failed while selecting a library - most didn't support asynchrous requests or didn't support TLS. I'm internally using MIO but not Tokio.

Answer (score -1):

The best way to make asynchronous I/O is to use tokio.

You can find a example HTTP+TLS in doc : https://tokio.rs/docs/getting-started/tls/

Comment: Link-only answers are frowned upon. In general, I would advise to include the relevant parts of the link in the answer itself; however in this particular case... I am not sure the question is salvageable, it's way too broad. SO deals best with specific questions, not tutorials.

Comment: I tried using that example - is there a non-blocking variant of Core#run()?

Comment: No, core.run (https://tokio-rs.github.io/tokio-core/tokio_core/reactor/struct.Core.html#method.run) run the event loop. If you want to add some stuff to the event loop, you could use core.handle (see https://tokio.rs/docs/getting-started/reactor/#handle).

Maybe you could re-use an event-loop, but I don't know how :D

Comment: The problem is, that I already have a loop and so on in my system - I need a way to integrate everything into that loop. That's not possible with Tokio, right?

Comment: I don't think so, tokio make his own wrapper for the event loop, and nothing in the doc explain how to use your own event loop.